# How to fix this weird variable?

Tags: math-mode, markdown

`$cutoff\_1$`
It shows like this: [image]

How can I reduce the blank space between 'off'?

Comment: You can use `\mathit{cutoff}`

Comment: Do you want to use this iside of an equation, is it part of a code or will it be just used inside of the text? Could you please provide come background information?

Comment: @leandriis It's a part of the equation

Comment: @Guido This works, cheers:)

Comment: never use math italic for multi-letter words, it is particular;y bad with `ff` but fairly bad always. The font is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product of variables not a word.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\mathit` to wrap a multi-letter variable in math mode, so you use

```
$\mathit{cutoff}\_1$
```

In any case, the space between the variable and the underscore looks too big. I would add a negative space

```
$\mathit{cutoff}\kern-2pt\_1$
```

the image below shows the difference between  the two

[image]